# How can I add an item by clicking on its adapter class and its data will display on tool bar in Android

Tags: android

when I am running the code in debugging ,it's working fine and give the desired output.
but when I am running its normal mode ,its crashing and giving above exception.
Getting Error when I m add an item through adapter into its BaseClass

```
HashMap<String,String> mMapWishList = new HashMap<String, String>();
                String id = mProducts.getSingleProductId.get(position);
                String name = mProducts.getSingleProductName.get(position);
                String price = mProducts.getSingleProductPrice.get(position);
                String oldPrice = mProducts.getSingleProductOldPrice.get(position);
                String discount = mProducts.getSingleProductDiscount.get(position);
                String description = mProducts.getSingleProductDescription.get(position);
```

getting only single item How can I add multiple items ?
getting this error
LogCatt Error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                                                     java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
atcom.example.dev.newkhreedapp1.views.adapters.Product_Adapter$1.onClick(Product_Adapter.java:193)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

why it's behaving like this ,not getting any clue.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: because, your arraylist dont have item you are trying to click

Comment: Products mProducts = new Products();      @Diveyesh , i am accessing item from another class

Comment: error shows that your arrylist has no items and you try to access first item from it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes into my mind is that you get your `mProducts` asynchronously, so during debug it's enough time to receive data, but during run mode it's failing. You should run this code after your products are retrieved from server.
Or another way not to get this error is add a check:

```
if (mProducts.size() > position) {
    String id = mProducts.getSingleProductId.get(position);
    String name = mProducts.getSingleProductName.get(position);
    String price = mProducts.getSingleProductPrice.get(position);
    String oldPrice = mProducts.getSingleProductOldPrice.get(position);
    String discount = mProducts.getSingleProductDiscount.get(position);
    String description = mProducts.getSingleProductDescription.get(position);
}
```

The crash should be gone, but you probably won't have data you need.

Comment: @Dinesh_Yogi Could you provide the code of what is `mProducts`. As I understand it's the object of your custom class

Comment: Products mProducts = new Products();  Where Products is another class

Comment: @Dinesh_Yogi Please provide the code of `Products` class and the code where you add data to `mProducts` object